# TFS 2013: Remove obsolete build controllers/agents not visible in admin

Tags: tfs

We have upgraded our TFS from 2010 to 2013, and the same time moved the TFS and databases to new servers, with new names.

One of the very few annoying effects (Probably due to moving the TFS to a server with a new name) is that the build controller/agent from the old server is still visible in lists of available build controllers/agents, but is not visible in the admin gui for build configurations and therefore not possible to remove.

Does anyone have had the same experience and furthermore have a solution of how to remove the traces of old (and not used/wanted) build controllers/agents?

Kind regards,
J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. 
Sorry, I found the solution myself now after continue searching and yet again scanning through the microsofts documentation! :)

It's possible to disable and delete controllers and agents through the Manage Build Controllers in Visual Studio.

[image: Manage Build Controllers in Visual Studio]

Also described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330987.aspx

Just make sure there is no builds in progress, but that's ofcourse also possible to handle through Manage Queues in Visual Studio.